# The meaning of indexing in a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I saw a loop in a demo code:

```
b <- 3
n <- 4

set.seed(1)

(i <- sample(rep(1:n, 
                 b)) )      
(g <- rep(1:b, 
          each=n) )      

(x <- rnorm(n) )           

m  <- rep(NA, max(g))      

for (j in 1:max(g) ) {      
  k    <- i[ g == j ]     
  m[j] <- mean(x[k])      
  print (j)
  print (k)
}
```

The max(g) = 3, so the loop run 3 times. but I don't understand the second row of the loop `k  <- i[ g == j ]`. What is the meaning here?  Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is a vector (created by `sample(rep(1:n, b))`).

`i[<something>]` indexes the elements of `i` for which `<something>` evaluates to `TRUE` (in this case when `g` is equal to `j)`.

`g` is another vector (created by `rep(1:b, each=n)`).

So

```
k <- i[ g == j ]
```

creates, for each value of `j` as the for loop runs (these values are `1:max(g)`), a vector `k` which is the subset of `i` for which the condition `g == j` is true.